# Dynamically add headers and columns to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview but currently it only sets one header. What I want it to do is add new header beside the other columns at the end of the table based on the number of users.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        int i = 6;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMT"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [user]";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {                                  
                        GridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = sdr["user_first_name"].ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://forums.asp.net/t/1788238.aspx?Add+header+column+to+dynamic+header+on+GridView

Comment: Similar but this is adding a new row below the header. I am trying to add headers next to my other headers though my sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TemplateField` columns to the GridView before binding the data. It could be done in the `Page_Load` event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [user]";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        TemplateField field = new TemplateField();
                        field.HeaderText = sdr["user_first_name"].ToString();
                        field.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(80);
                        GridView1.Columns.Add(field);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```